# Creating text file to store string in Python using a list

Tags: python, string, list, text

I am writing code that looks for a specific string that could occur in a vacancy. I have some vacancies in a local folder in a .txt format. I want to search all files for the string and then store that string in a new file that will contain all filenames.

I created a list that contains all vacancies because I do not want the new file containing the searched string to appear when I search for a string a second time

I have the following code:

```
import os
import glob
from datetime import date
import time

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

search = "engineer"


vacancies = [filename for filename in glob.glob("*.txt") if not filename.endswith('keyword.txt')]

for filename in vacancies:
   with open ("C:\\LOCATION\\txt"+'\\'+filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
       for line in f:
           line = line.lower


for filename in vacancies:
    with open ("C:\\LOCATION\\txt"+'\\'+filename) as f:
     
        if search in f.read():
            f = open(d1 + " " + search + " keyword.txt","a+", encoding='utf-8')
            f.write("Found it in " + filename + '\n')
            f.close
```

I would expect my list to filter out the new file, however I get an errormessage stating: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '05/11/2020 engineer keyword.txt'

Can someone explain why this code is not working?

Comment: Side note: `line = line.lower` has no effect.

Comment: Could you provide example text.

Comment: Did you expect the file `05/11/2020 engineer keyword.txt` to exist?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I would expect the file to be created if the word "engineer" would be found in at least one file of the files in the list. The list contains  only the filenames, not the actual content

with regard to the line=line.lower; thank you, I had not tested that line of code yet because of the primary issue. I would have tested that after. Any recommendations?

Comment: @AlexNe the list contains only filenames, not the actual content. What would you need?

Comment: Did you expect the file to exist in the `C:\LOCATION\txt` directory? Because you use this directory the first two times with `open()` but not the third time.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Could be a misunderstanding on my part but here I go: I expect all files that need to be searched to fill the "vacancies" list to be in the C:\LOCATION\txt directory. a print statement for the list does indeed show all the files. In this directory and print statement the 05/11/2020 engineer keyword.txt file does not occur. I also expect this as the f=open statement should create the 05/11/2020 engineer keyword.txt file which contains al the filenames in which the search string is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the FileNotFoundError was given is because of the slashes in the d1 variable. The text file could not be created with slashes. After swapping slash"" for hyphen"-", the code worked just fine